# capture part of a string with regex using PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I can't seem to find a function that captures and returns a regex'ed string.

```
$string = "hello123!";
$string = regexfunction($string, "/([0-9]*)/");
echo $string;
```

Prints

```
123
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/preg_match) for this, although the syntax will be slightly different:

```
$string = "hello123!";
preg_match("/[0-9]+/", $string, $matches);
print $matches[0]; // 123
```

Comment: Oh cool. I should have read the documentation a little more closely.
Thank you.